# How to make a MS Word fillable form (with macros) usable for non-Office users?

Tags: vba, forms, pdf, ms-word

I have created a fillable form in MS Word. It uses dropdown picklists and other fillable developer tools. It has two macros. The first depends on the users selection from one dropdown, and determines what values will be available in the second dropdown. The second depends on the users selection in the second dropdown, and determines what text will be displayed below (i.e. what questions the user will be asked).

Is there anyway to make this useable for people who are no MS Word users?

My initial thought is convert it to a pdf. But when it save the doc as a pdf it looses all form-filling functionality. (as if printed).

Comment: Even though this project has macros, your question is off-topic for this forum. It should be in a general Word forum like Super User https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/microsoft-word or Microsoft Answers http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_word. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: Your initial mistake was to design a document that requires macros. This not only makes it difficult to distribute your form, as it will get blocked by email clients, but it will limit the number of people that are willing to open it as it requires disabling their macro security. You need to look for an alternative that doesn't require the user to run code. Perhaps something hosted on the web?

Comment: The short answer is no.